# Transfer data form one browser tab to another

Tags: javascript, html, cross-domain, data-sharing

I would like to capture data from one tab and use it to prefill my form in another tab.

Let's say a loan officer has their property data sheet open in one tab and they want to order a property inspection. If the property inspector's order system is not integrated with the bank's system they would then need to type the relevant data into a new order form or copy/past a field at a time.

I would like the Property Inspector's order form to be pre-populated somehow from the bank property sheet. Can one tab read another? Can I somehow drag/drop one tab onto another? Can I do this in straight javascript or would I need to create a plugin?

How would I crack this nut, preferably in a secure and cross browser fashion?

Edit: This was tagged as a duplicate question. Here is why it is not. The solution proposed in the other thread requires you to be the author of both tab content so you can use Local Storage or Cookies to pass messages. In my situation, the property inspection company is not the developer of the bank's web site, and it is on another domain.

Comment: Browser tabs are just like new windows in this respect. Unless you use JavaScript in one window (tab) to open the second, you can't pass data directly between them. One workaround it to use cookies or localStorage, but the two tabs must be viewing the same domain for that to work.

Comment: So I guess I would have to build a plugin for each browser to do this.